# Bootstrap Menu DropDown not working on a page with embedded header.html file

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I have created a project with jQuery Embedded common header.html file on all pages (including index.html , etc.)

I added Bootstrap in this. Now, DropDown Menu in header.html is working fine; but not on other pages (with included header.html)

Also, even the Menu Toggle doesn't work fine (It doesn't go up back). I have tried all way to resolve this, but nothing beneficiary.

Does DropDown in Bootstrap Menu Not Supported with header files added with jQuery?

`header.html`:

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
         <head>
            <title>The Best Learning Website</title>
        
            <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="max-age=600, public">
            
            <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
            <!-- <link href="data:text/css;charset=utf-8," data-href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" 
             id="bs-theme-stylesheet" /> -->
            <script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
            
            <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet.css" /> 
            
            <script>
                $(window).scroll(function () {
                var y = $(this).scrollTop();
                var x = $(this).scrollLeft();
                $('#blurry').css('background-position', parseInt(-x) + 'px ' + parseInt(-y) + 'px');
                });
            </script>
        
            <style>
             
            .inarow{ margin: 0 auto; }
             
             .logo{ width: 15%; height:140px; margin:1% auto; padding:0%; }
            </style>
         </head>
            
         <body> 
         <!-- nav -->
         <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <br/>
                <!--header -->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-3"> <img alt="SP Logo" src="images/SS-Training-Center-sp-white.png" > </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6" class="shadow">
                        <h1>
                            <span style="color:green;font-weight:bold;">SP</span>
                            <span style="color:#053d63;font-weight:bold;">- A Complete solution pad  for  all  your</span>
                            <span style="color:#e00000;font-weight:bold;">Problems</span>
                            <span>!</span>
                        </h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3"> <img alt="Solution Pad" src="images/sp-pad-logo-white.png"> </div> 
                </div>
            
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
              
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Menu</a>
            </div>
        
            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
             <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="what-we-do.html">What We Do</a></li>
                        <li><a href="who-we-are.html">Who We Are</a></li>
                        <!-- <li><a href="see-my-work-here.html">My Work</a></li> -->
                        <li> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Free Stuffs</a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                <li tabindex="-1"><a href="study-problems-and-issues.html">Study Problems?</a></li>
                                <li tabindex="-1"><a href="study-problems-and-issues.html">Learning Inabilities?</a></li>
                                <li>Study Depression</li>
                                <li>More Stuffs Coming Soon! Plz Stay Connected!</li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Need Help ?</a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu"> 
                                <li><a href="#">Get Yourself Trained</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Provide us Feedback ONLINE</a></li>
                                <li><a href="contact-us.html">Contact Us</a></li>
                                <li><a href="docs/For-Institutions.doc">Download Training Request Offline</a></li>
                                <li><a href="docs/To-Institutions.doc">Download Training Quotation Offline</a></li>
                                <li><a href="docs/Feedback-Form.doc">Download Offline Feedback Form</a></li>
                                <li><a href="training-modules.html">Our Training Modules</a></li>
                                <li><a href="sp-flash.html">ss-flash</a></li>
                                <li><a href="ss-youtube.html">ss-youtube</a></li>
                                <li><a href="mahavaani-hindi.html">mahavaani hindi</a></li>
                                <li><a href="inspirational-quotes-english.html">inspirational Quotes</a></li>
                                <li><a href="motivational-speeches.html">motivational-speeches</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>                   
                </ul>
             </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
            </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
           </nav>
         </body>
        </html>
```

`index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="max-age=600, public">
    
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!-- <link href="data:text/css;charset=utf-8," data-href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" 
     id="bs-theme-stylesheet" /> -->
    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet.css" />
    
    <style>
     #wrapPad{
        border-radius: 10px;
        border: solid thick #9f9f9f;
        border-left: outset; 
        border-right: ridge;
        border-top: ridge;
        border-bottom: inset;
        background-color:#e6e6e6; /* or  #efeded , #c1cdcd , ffe4c4 , #eeeeee , #c1cdc1 , #e6e6e6 , #cccccc , */
        text-align: center;
        /* <shadow> = inset? && [ <length>{2,4} && color? ] */
        box-shadow: 3px 30px 70px 5px #05f;
        /*  shadows of right, bottom; glow of box, color of border of box */
        padding: 3%;
        vertical-align:middle;
     }
     
     #wrapScreen{
        background-color:#1f1f1f;
        text-align: center;
        /* <shadow> = inset? && [ <length>{2,4} && color? ] */
        box-shadow: -1px -1px 1px 2px black;
        /*  shadows of right, bottom; glow of box, color of border of box */
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding:0%;
     }   
     .icons{ border: none; /* list-style: none; margin:0 auto; float:left; */ }
     .contact{ text-align: center; }
     
 </style>
    
    <script> 
        $(function(){
            $("#includedContent").load("header.html"); 
        });
    </script>
    <script>
        $(function(){
            $("#footerDiv").load("footer.html"); 
        });
    </script>   
 </head>
 <body>
<div class="container">
    <!-- Nav -->
    <div id="includedContent"></div>
    <br />
   
   <div class="row">
     <div class="row" id="wrapPad">
        <div id="wrapScreen" class="row" class="img-responsive">
         <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8">
          <img src="images/pic01.jpg" alt="Solution Pad to your Problems" title="Solution Pad to your Problems" 
           name="slide" style="border:0px;width:80%;height:70%;" />
          </div>
         <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4" class="headingImg">
            <h2 id="headingImg">head of img descr</h2>
            <p id="TextImg">text para</p>
         </div>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="inarow" id="buttons3">
            <a href="http://yourgrowth.in/contact-us.html"> 
                <div id="btnMain"> <div id="btnMainBtn"> 
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </div> </div> 
            </a>
        </div>                  
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    <br/>       
    <div id="footerDiv"></div> 
    <br/>
 </body>
</html>
```

**one more html file code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>SP - The Page is Not Available</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="max-age=600, public">
    
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!-- <link href="data:text/css;charset=utf-8," data-href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" 
     id="bs-theme-stylesheet" /> -->
    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet.css" /> 
    
    <script>
        $(function(){
          $("#includedContent").load("header.html"); 
        });
    </script>
</head>
 <body>
   <div class="container">
        <!-- Nav -->
        <div id="includedContent"></div>
        <br />
        
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
      <h1>Sorry, the page you visited is not Found!</h1>
      <br />
      <h2>The Possible causes of this error you see, may be either of the following:</h2>
      <p>The Web Page you are looking for is not available or is MISSPELLED!</p>
      <p>This Site is under maintenance for now...!</p>
      <p>Also, Check for the Internet Connection.</p>
      <h4> Make Sure, you add .html at Last of each page you wish to visit Directly (via URL)</h4>
      <br />
     </div>
    </div>
    
    <section>
        Return to Homepage
    </section>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the issue Resolved a few months ago!

To Resolve such an issue, you must keep in mind these points:

1. As, header.html & footer.html are to be added in index.html (or any
   other page), thus Don't add (Style, Scripts) links again in header.html e.g. (Add
   them only once in page & not in header.html again)
2. Add Only those Styles & Scripts that you need in header.html only.
3. And Most Important; Inside each submenu item, make sure to add class="dropdown-menu" & role="menu" attributes like below:

   [Home](http://solupad.com/index.html)

   ```
   <li id="Phf"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Problems? &#8681;</a>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" style="color:red">
       <li><a href="study-problems-and-issues.html">Study problems & non-interests</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Poor Learning ability</a></li>
       <li><a href="why-my-memory-is-so-weak.html">Is MEMORY too WEAK?</a></li>
       <li><a href="why-my-memory-is-so-weak.html">Lack of Concentration</a></li

       <li><a href="#">Unable to Perform your work well?</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Poor Work Performance</a></li>
       <li><a href="why-life-is-such-painful-depressed-lazy-joyless-and-unhappy.html">Depressed or Unhappy Life</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Parenting Failures</a></li>
     </ul>
   </li>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Delete bootstrap.min.css,jQuery.min.js,bootstrap.min.js from header.html/footer.html and  other related java script and css file which already have been added into parent html(index.html/jsp) file